# Kodaira-Spencer map in logarithmic geometry

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, moduli-spaces

Can anyone provide a reference for the Kodaira-Spencer map in the logarithmic geometry setting?

Comment: http://www.math.brown.edu/~abrmovic/LOGGEOM/lectures-satellite.pdf - not sure if this helps